# Rails message: ActionView::MissingTemplate

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting an error that I cannot figure out:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template cluster/delete_stuff.erb in view path app/views)
<...snip trace...>
Rendering rescues/layout (internal_server_error)
```

I am "enhancing" others code and am following the convention they set up, where they have have code like:

```
<%= render :partial => "other_stuff" %>
```

And a file named **_other_stuff.html.erb** and it all works, but when I copy these little snippets, I get the above error. Any ideas? Something is going on here that I need to figure out.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Turns out that I did not have a

`render :something`

in my controller method, so I guess Rails figured that there must be a "delete_stuff.erb" somewhere to know what to do. Added a render and the error message goes away.

Answer (score 5):

`ActionView` will look for templates/partials in the current controllers view folder, unless its view path has been changed in the controller—you can [prepend and append](http://railsapi.com/doc/rails-v2.3.8/classes/ActionController/Base.html) different view paths for it to try and match first. Since you mention partials specifically, have a look at the documentation on [partials](http://railsapi.com/doc/rails-v2.3.8/classes/ActionView/Partials.html).

Do you have a `_delete_stuff.html.erb` file in your views/cluster directory? If not, where is the `_delete_stuff.html.erb` partial? If it's not in the same directory, you will have to call `render :partial => 'other_directory/delete_stuff'` for your partial to appear.

Comment: Yes, I have a _delete_stuff.html.erb file in the views/cluster directory. I changed it to delete_stuff.erb and of course that error disappeared and another one appeared. It also then was different then all other similar view snippets that I copied from.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a problem with background job.
Sidekiq was running with old code (some deploy did not restart it properly).

After killing sidekiq and deamon next start it has worked fine without missing template

Answer (score 0):

I found that in my case a sub-function was failing before the render statement.  There was no error handing in that area of code, so I had to put in debug statements to discover where the error was to resolve it, then this error message went away.