# Rspec testing authentication pages couldn't pass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm flowing  ROR tutorials  on chapter 8. I got stuck with testing authentication_pages. I checked with the book three times already, Couldn't found any problem  out there. Anyone please take a look , your help will be greatly appreciated!

```
Failures:

  1) AuthenticationPages signin with valid information 
     Failure/Error: fill_in "Password", with: user.Password
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `Password' for #<User:0x007fee4d55ed60>
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:27:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) AuthenticationPages signin with valid information 
     Failure/Error: fill_in "Password", with: user.Password
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `Password' for #<User:0x007fee4d668d50>
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:27:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) AuthenticationPages signin with valid information 
     Failure/Error: fill_in "Password", with: user.Password
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `Password' for #<User:0x007fee4ba5ed08>
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:27:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  4) AuthenticationPages signin with valid information 
     Failure/Error: fill_in "Password", with: user.Password
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `Password' for #<User:0x007fee4d68b008>
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:27:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.72208 seconds
44 examples, 4 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:30 # AuthenticationPages signin with valid information 
rspec ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:31 # AuthenticationPages signin with valid information 
rspec ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:32 # AuthenticationPages signin with valid information 
rspec ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:33 # AuthenticationPages signin with valid information
```

authentication_pages_spec.rb file:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "AuthenticationPages" do
    subject { page }
    describe "signin page" do
    before { visit signin_path }
it { should have_content('Sign in') }
it { should have_title('Sign in') }
end
describe "signin" do
    before { visit signin_path }
    describe "with invalid information" do
        before { click_button "Sign in"}

        it { should have_title('Sign in') }
        it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error', text: 'Invalid') }

        describe "after visiting another page" do
            before { click_link "Home" }
            it { should_not have_selector('div.alert.alter-error') }
        end
    end
    describe "with valid information" do
        let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
        before do
            fill_in "Email", with: user.email.upcase
            fill_in "Password", with: user.Password
            click_button "Sign in"
        end
        it { should have_title(user.name) }
        it { should have_link('Profile', href: user_path(user)) }
        it { should have_link('Sign out', href: signout_path) }
        it { should_not have_link('Sign in', href: signin_path) }
    end
end
end
```

sessions_controller.rb file:

```
  class SessionsController < ApplicationController
    def new
    end
def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
    else
        flash.now[:error]= 'Invalid email/password combination' # Not quite right!
        render 'new'
    end
end
    def destroy
    end
end
```

routes.rb file

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :users
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
  root to: 'static_pages#home'
  match '/signup',  to: 'users#new',            via: 'get'
  match '/signin',  to: 'sessions#new',         via: 'get'
  match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy',     via: 'delete'
  match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help',    via: 'get'
  match '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about',   via: 'get'
  match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact', via: 'get'
end
```

Comment: Thanks ! it is lower case hehe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think *apneadiving* is right, it looks like it should be lower case. I also had a look at [GitHub code for the tutorial](https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app_rails_4/blob/master/spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb)

```
describe "with valid information" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      before do
        fill_in "Email",    with: user.email.upcase
        fill_in "Password", with: user.password
        click_button "Sign in"
      end
```

it's lower case there too. And just make it sure I just also checked Ruby is a case sensitive language, according to the Ruby Programming language book by David Flanagan, Yukihiro Matsumoto.

Comment: @Snailwalker It could be that you are missing something  sample_app/app/views folder (perhaps sample_app/app/views/sessions/ new.html.erb template) or you might need to add a render method call in to your controller. Sorry I don't have your code but I hope this link will help further: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019369/rails-message-actionviewmissingtemplate